# Select specific columns by their alias, and later order by it

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

My table are the following

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | priority |  User  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        2 | [null] |
|  2 |        1 | [null] |
|  3 |        3 | Tony   |
|  4 |        2 | John   |
|  5 |        2 | Andy   |
|  6 |        1 | Mike   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

My goal is to extract them, and order by the following combined conditions:

1. priority = 1
2. User is null

```
+----+----------+--------+-----------+
| id | priority |  User  | peak_rows |
+----+----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |        2 | [null] | 1         |
|  2 |        1 | [null] | 1         |
|  6 |        1 | Mike   | 0         |
|  3 |        3 | Tony   | 1         |
|  4 |        2 | John   | 0         |
|  5 |        2 | Andy   | 0         |
+----+----------+--------+-----------+
```

This is what I guess I can do

```
select
    id,
    CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c1,
    CASE WHEN User is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c2,
    c1 + c2 AS peak_rows
FROM mytable
ORDER BY peak_rows DESC
```

but it cause an error:

```
ERROR:  column "c1" does not exist
LINE 5:  c1+ c2as pp
         ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 129
```

I don't know why I make 2 columns(c1 and c2), but I can not use it later.

Any good idea to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making two columns and using them later, you are making them and want to use them at the same time. You could use a subquery.

```
SELECT a.id, a.priority, a.User, a.c1 + a.c2 AS peak_rows
FROM
(SELECT id,
        priority,
        User,
        CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c1,
        CASE WHEN User IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c2,
 FROM mytable) a
ORDER BY peak_rows DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your aim is to order by those `c1` and `c2`, so you can directly use in the `order by` clause. You just need to interchange `0` and `1` in the `case..when` statements. And depending on your `priority=1` criteria `id=2` must stay at the top.

```
with mytable( id, priority, "User" ) as
(
 select 1 , 2,  null  union all
 select 2,  1,  null  union all
 select 3,  3, 'Tony' union all
 select 4,  2, 'John' union all
 select 5,  2, 'Andy' union all
 select 6,  1, 'Mike'
)    
select * 
  from mytable
 order by ( case when priority = 1   then 0 else 1 end ) +
          ( case when "User" is null then 0 else 1 end );

id  priority   User
--  -------- -------
2   1         [null]
1   2         [null]
6   1          Mike
3   3          Tony
4   2          John
5   2          Andy
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KNBWJW52015)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    id,
    CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c1,
    CASE WHEN User is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c2,
    (CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + ( CASE WHEN User is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS peak_rows
FROM mytable
ORDER BY peak_rows DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this also works, but I don't want to repeat the code.